# Is there a minimal example of taking a picture in Android Jetpack? (no preview, no user interaction)

Tags: android-camera2, android-jetpack

I am following the guidance in the Android Jetpack CameraX docs, and it is significantly more involved than I was hoping for than the "Hello World" I was hoping for.  My case is much more simple:

1. The permissions are already taken care of
2. **No preview window** (this is where I can't figure out how to adapt their demo to my needs)
3. No user controls at all - no focusing or button pressing or anything
4. Just `myCamera.click() { binaryPhoto -> { work_with_the_picture(binaryPhoto) }`

Have you ever come across an absolute minimal photo-taking example that works with jetpack and camera2?

Comment: Also keen to know this, did you find a viable solution via Jetpack in the end?

Comment: nope.  (grumble)